# Selector does not work for a button

Tags: android

Consider:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_on"  ></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_on"  ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_off"></item>
</selector>
```

Button in layout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/main_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
/>
```

want to change background on click, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not work mean ? Any error ?

Comment: when I click on the button does not change the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
android:state_pressed="true"
```

Something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_off" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

**Edit**
For your requirement use this

```
boolean isButtonClicked=false;
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // Then you should add add click listener for your button.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.main_button) {
                isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; // toggle the boolean flag
                v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.btn_led_on : R.drawable.btn_led_off);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes I tried ，only the state_pressed can work 。but I want the button  by click to change the background not press

Comment: I used your method can be，but why the selector not work @Kiran Benny Joseph

Comment: @Jevis `android:state_pressed="true"` only works when the button get pressed and if you release your button it will go to `android:state_pressed="false"`. If my code helped you please accept this as answer.

Comment: ok，thanks for you answer ，I will accept this as answer . can you tell me why I code like this '<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_on" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_led_on" android:state_selected="true"></item>'   is not work @ Kiran Benny Joseph

Comment: @Jevis You can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>
</selector>
```